How do I make a check to make sure a recipe is only saved once?
So i have an Activity thats saves a recipe and sends data to firebase. How to make a check that the recipe is not saved only once regardless of how many times the user clicked on the button?
Below is the code for the activity.
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private EditText edName,edCal;
    private DatabaseReference mDataBase;
    private ImageView imgRec;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    private Uri uploadUri;
    FirebaseAuth auth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);
        init();

    }

    public void init(){
        addRec = binding.buttonAddRec;
        edName = binding.editTextName;
        edCal = binding.editTextCal;
        mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Const.KEY_RECIPE);
        imgRec = binding.imageRec;
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("ImageDB");
    }
    //Called only when the uploadImage function is executed
    //So yeah activity is closed only when imageUpload is done, I couldn't think of anything better
    public void saveRecipe(){
        String id = mDataBase.push().getKey();
        String name = edName.getText().toString();
        String cal = edCal.getText().toString();
        RecipeBd newRecipe = new RecipeBd(id,name,cal,uploadUri.toString());
        if(id != null)
        {
            mDataBase.child(id).setValue(newRecipe);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent savedRecipe = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PickRecipeActivity.class);
            startActivity(savedRecipe);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
    //func of the buttonAddRecipe
    public void onClickSave(View view){
        
        String name = edName.getText().toString();
        String cal = edCal.getText().toString();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(cal)){
            uploadImage();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Empty Field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    //func of the buttonAddPhoto
    public void onClickChooseImage(View view){
        getImage();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1 && data!=null && data.getData() != null) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("MyLog","Image URI:" + data.getData());
                imgRec.setImageURI(data.getData());

            }
        }
    }
        
    private void getImage(){
        Intent intentChooser = new Intent();
        intentChooser.setType("image/*");
        intentChooser.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intentChooser,1);

    }
    //upload on db Firebase
    private void uploadImage(){
        Bitmap bitMap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgRec.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
        final StorageReference mRef = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+"Recipe");//The names depend on milliseconds
        UploadTask up = mRef.putBytes(byteArray);
        Task<Uri> task = up.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                return mRef.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                uploadUri = task.getResult();
                saveRecipe();

            }
        });
    }
}

Maybe i can add a progress bar over activity? or is there a better way?
layout code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageRec"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Write a name of recipe"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonAddPhoto" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name of Recipe"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Calories"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextName"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddRec"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:onClick="onClickSave"
        android:text="Add Recipe"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextCal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextCal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextCal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:onClick="onClickChooseImage"
        android:text="add photo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.733"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageRec" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Thanks for your help!
